# How to run celery schedule instantly?

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat

I have a celery schedule which is configured like this:

```py
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "runs-every-30-seconds": {
        "task": "tasks.refresh",
        "schedule": timedelta(hours=1)
    },
}
```

After testing I find that this schedule is started after 1 hour, but I want to run this schedule instantly and again after 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean at startup, do it in [AppConfig.ready()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) (new in django 1.7):

```
# my_app/__init__.py:

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    def ready(self):
        tasks.refresh.delay()
```

Also see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/#module-django.apps

If you're only doing this for the tests, I'd rather call/delay the tasks directly than testing the celery scheduler itself.

Comment: I don't know why but with this my task runs twice, first one when I start django server, second one when I run celery worker with beat