# Running celery task when celery beat starts

Tags: django, celery

How do I schedule a task to run when I start celery beat then again in 1 hours and so.

Currently I have schedule in settings.py:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'update_database': {
        'task': 'myapp.tasks.update_database',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=60),
    },
}
```

I saw a post from 1 year here on stackoverflow asking the same question: 
[How to run celery schedule instantly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23098269/how-to-run-celery-schedule-instantly)

However this does not work for me, because my celery worker get 3-4 requests for the same task, when I run django server

I'm starting my worker and beat like this:

```
celery -A dashboard_web worker -B --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10
```

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 3):

## Crontab schedule

You could try to use a `crontab` schedule instead which will run every hour and start 1 min after initialization of the scheduler. **Warning:** you might want to do it a couple of minutes later in case it takes longer to start, otherwise you might need to wait the full hour.

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
from datetime import datetime

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'update_database': {
        'task': 'myapp.tasks.update_database',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=(datetime.now().minute + 1) % 60),
    },
}
```

Reference: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules

## Ready method of MyAppConfig

In order to ensure that your task is run right away, you could use the same method as before to create the periodic task without adding `1` to the `minute`. Then, you call your task in the `ready` method of `MyAppConfig` which is called whenever your app is ready.

```
#myapp/apps.py

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "myapp"

    def ready(self):
        from .tasks import update_database
        update_database.delay()
```

Please note that you could also create the periodic task directly in the `ready` method if you were to use `django_celery_beat`.

**Edit:** *Didn't see that the second method was already covered in the link you mentioned. I'll leave it here in case it is useful for someone else arriving here.*

Comment: You need to use `minute=(datetime.now().minute+1) % 60` or celerybeat will raise an exception when executed at the last minute of the hour

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the configuration parameter `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True`

Something like this

```
app.conf.CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
```

Comment: That is not a good recommendation. It means that every task will never be sent to the celery worker but just executed right when they are called and by the process that calls them.

Comment: To be fair, this is ok if you need to run Celery tasks on the same server running Celery Beat (could be valid use cases), but just remember that any additional Celery Task fired off from these tasks will all run in EAGER mode -- they'll all be synchronous executions. While that's good for 'chaining' a bunch of tasks together, if you want to fire off tasks to run in parallel, they never will.